# create RadioGroup programmatically

Tags: android, radio-group

I am getting arrayList [5,8,13,18,19] from the server and I would like to create a RadioGroup in the xml file and not as AlertDialog. After selecting the diserable items, I will put the selected items in arrayList and transmit the query to the server after clicking the OK button. How can I create such as dynamic RadioGroup? I have tried this but I dont know how to loog through to get it to wrok.

I appreciate any help.

xml fiel:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bustracker.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Select route: "
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lila"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

createRadioButton method:

```
private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
    final ArrayList<RadioButton> rb = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {


    }
    ll.addView(rg);// you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout

    final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ll.addView(submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            }
            ll.removeView(submit);

        }
    });
}
```